# Marhall/unmarshall JSON with array as a top-level element

Tags: json, jaxb

I need to unmarshall JSON having array as a top-level element:

```
[
    {
        "test1": 
        {
            "name": "Boost",
            "fraction": 0.55
        }
    },
    {
        "test2": 
        {
            "name": "Boost",
            "fraction": 0.55
        }
    }
]
```

My top-level element looks like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Wrapper<T> {

    @XmlTransient
    private List<T> items;

    public Wrapper() {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Wrapper(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

}
```

Unmarshalling is done in this method:

```
private <T> T get(String path, Class<T> aClass) {
    WebTarget target = root.path(path);
    Invocation.Builder request = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
    return request.get(aClass);
}
```

When I tried to marshall an existing object into json I have got the following result:

```
    {
   "items" : [
        {
            "test1": 
            {
                "name": "Boost",
                "fraction": 0.55
            }
        },
        {
            "test2": 
            {
                "name": "Boost",
                "fraction": 0.55
            }
        }
    ]}
```

How can I force JAXB to skip this `items` key?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using GenericType `new GenericType<List<MyObject>>() {}`